# What does this error code mean? JSONDecodeError: Expecting Value

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm using discord.py to create a bot for my server. I'm following a tutorial made by Spyros, and I'm getting this error:

```py
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)]
```

It's just an empty JSON file, just curly brackets with no data.
Anyone knows what I can do? I'll post more code if needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JSONDecode is expecting data and as you said, you are passing an empty JSON "file"